# QT cast a widget to a combobox

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qcombobox

I have a table[][] of widgets and depending on a value that I have I'll instantiate that widget to a QLabel or to a QCombobox.

```
QWidget *tab[9][9];

if(modele->firstvalue(i,j) ==0) {
    tab[i][j]= new QComboBox();
    tab[i][j]->setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid red");
    ((QComboBox)tab[i][j]).addItem("Test");

}
else {
    tab[i][j] = new QLabel(QString::number(modele->firstvalue(i,j)));
}
```

So in my widget after the execution I see all the comboboxes but not with the values (no items added)

**PS:**
It's about a sudoku game. If there are a lot multiple values then I create a combobox with all the possible values, else a QLabel with a single value.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is in this line:

```
((QComboBox)tab[i][j]).addItem("Test");
```

It's a bit obfuscated due to the C cast. Had you used the C++ cast, you'd write:

```
static_cast<QComboBox>(tab[i][j]).addItem("Test");
```

The `static_cast` is redundant syntax, and it's now obvious that the code means:

```
QComboBox(tab[i][j]).addItem("Test");
```

As you can see, you're creating a temporary combo box with `tab[i][j]` as the parent, then adding an item to it, and immediately destroying it when the scope is exited. The original combo box you've created 3 lines above it is not modified here.

Instead, you need to write (don't use C-style casts in C++):

```
static_cast<QComboBox*>(tab[i][j])->addItem("Test");
```

Ideally, write the code so you won't need the cast at all:

```
auto box = new QComboBox;
box->setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid red");
box->addItem("Test");
tab[i][j] = box;
```

Comment: good answer, just to mention it there is also a special Qt cast: [qobject_cast](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qobject.html#qobject_cast), which should be used for `QObject` based dynamic casts. in this case `qobject_cast<QComboBox*>(tab[i][j])->addItem("Test");`

Comment: @xander `qobject_cast` is an alternative to `dynamic_cast`, not some general "use on `QObject` cast". When the type is known, you're supposed to use `static_cast`, not `dynamic_cast`, and thus not `qobject_cast` either. It gets worse: when the compiler can deduce the static type, a `dynamic_cast` can get promoted to a static cast. When you use `qobject_cast`, this optimization can't happen. **TL;DR** Use `static_cast` when you can, and `dynamic_cast` only when you can not.

Comment: @xander A `qobject_cast` is an optimization over `dynamic_cast` when dealing with types you're sure compiler won't be able to resolve at compile time, and becomes necessary when compiling without RTTI.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
((QComboBox)tab[i][j]).addItem("Test");
```

use:

```
((QComboBox*)tab[i][j]).addItem("Test");
```

As your grid has pointers to widgets